# Passing container between jobs

Tags: concourse

I'm most likely looking at things the wrong way, but whilst playing around with concourse setting up our CI pipeline, I had an idea to try and run our unit tests, JS unit tests, and e2e tests all in parallel, which made me think of having them all as separate jobs. This would mean though that an initial job would need to be run first to install all the dependencies ready for the 3 subsequent jobs to then be able to run the tests.

I assume that I should really do this using `aggregate` for the steps in the plan of a single job, but it got me thinking - can I pass the result from a job to a subsequent job with any changes made?

I've looked at the `passed` option on a `get` step which seems like what I'm after, but I'm guessing that if I used this I wouldn't be getting the previous jobs docker image with all dependencies installed, but rather the docker image that it was given before it installed dependencies?

Hopefully I've explained that well enough.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. You could create a pipeline that does all of the image building then saving that either as a docker image somewhere on dockerhub, or tarring it up and saving it in S3, and using that later in another pipeline.

Comment: Yeah I thought that was the case. That's a shame but will have to work around it. Thanks

Comment: @Josh I believe it is possible to do this using a custom resource. While I have not seen a resource usable for this purpose, I don't see any reason why it couldn't be done, similar to the community npm-cache-resource (https://github.com/ymedlop/npm-cache-resource).